# Exception привести к типу String

Tags: android, исключения

Как можно в try/catch а именно в блоке catch

```
catch (e: Exception) {
        e.log()
```

e привести к типу String и сравнить его с какой то строкой?

Comment: Зачем? Ибо можно по разному в зависимости от целей.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб мне нужно сравнивать e с определенной ошибкой и если текст ошибки совпадает, тогда отправлять стучаться с помощью EventBus'a

Comment: Если сообщение в ошибку вы сами пишите/точно знаете какое оно, то можно юзать `e.getMessage()`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб годиться, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего должно помочь получение сообщения, заключённого в ошибке так:

```
String message = e.getMessage();
```